# Firebase Realtime Database Query All Items in Flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I'm trying to get all the stored items inside the firebase realtime database and i'm not able to get them. Here the function that i'm using. I want to get all the keys stored inside the bdd(attached a screenshot of the bdd). The size of the returned items is 0 always.

```
Future<int> getEntriesNumber() async {
final response = FirebaseDatabase.instance
  .reference();
var entries = [];
response.onValue.forEach((v) => entries.add(v));
print("getEntries $entries");
return entries.length;
}
```

[Bdd Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vde0m.png)

Thank you!

Solved with this:

```
  DataSnapshot response = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .reference().once();
  print(response.value.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve with something like this:

```js
final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('//hereTheCollectionName');

databaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  //snapshot.value will contain each register in your database.
});
```

You should use `async`/`await` to wait for all registers.